# GAS: GUI Builder, File Upload, Submit Button

Tags: google-apps-script

I already read some answers to this question on stackoverflow but I was not able to get my case working.

I have the components in GUI Builder and the code runs to function respondToSubmit after pressing Submit button, but the fileName is undefined. fileName is the content of Name in Input Fields in component File Upload. Any Ideas what is wrong?

```
function respondToSubmit(e) {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var fileBlob = e.parameter.fileName;

  throw(fileBlob); // fileBlob = undefined!!!

  return app;

}
```

[image]

**RECENT CODE:**

function doPost(e) {

throw("doPost"); // never thrown so code does not run here!

var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var fileBlob = e.parameter.FileUpload1;

return app;

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to have your labels, text boxes, and submit buttons all in a Flow Panel, which then has to be enveloped by a Form Panel.  I had this exact same problem, even the 'Unexpected Error'.  I solved it by putting all of those elements into a Flow Panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of buttons - one is the regular button and the other is a Submit button (which can be placed only on a form panel)

1. Make sure you are using the Submit button and not a regular button
2. When you use a Submit button, there is no need to provide a handler function. Submit buttons, by default get handled by a special function called doPost(e). So, write a doPost function and you will be able to filename parameter.

The FileUpload widget documentation has a nice example of how this is done.

Comment: I first tried this solution but I was unable to get the code run in function doPost(e) --> Error encountered: An unexpected error occured. So I tried it like in my question, but was not able to get my case working. In the doPost-variation the function code was exactly the same as in my respondToSubmit-variation. I used in both cases a Submit button and placed it in a form panel.I try to get this working as a web-site script. Any further adwises?

Comment: In the respondToSubmit-variation the code at least run in the function after pressing submit-button so it was slightly better! ;-)

Comment: The unexpected error usually occurs when you try to access a UI element without the ID set. Can you ensure all the UI elements you are trying to access have their ID set properly

Comment: I think so... In section Base the UI elements have as ID values their default values: FileUpload1 and SubmitButton1. One thing I'm wondering is that when the code is in the respondToSubmit function is it really possible to get the parameter e.parameter.fileName just like that from another UI element, in this case from FileUpload element. So does the code search all the UI elements and try to find in some element a parameter called fileName?

Comment: So here is step by step what I tried first: I added in GUI builder FileUpload and SubmitButton elements. The elements had as ID:s their default ID:s: FileUpload1 and SubmitButton1. I defined in the FileUpload element as Name filename. The Submit button was placed on a Form Panel. I wrote the doPost function, see above, hoping the code would run there automatically after pressing the SubmitButton --> Code did not run there + Error encountered: An unexpected error occured. I assumed that the code somehow finds filename parameter from the FileUpload element so I wrote no code in doGet().

Comment: The second try was to change the name of doPost --> respondToSubmit. Then I defined in GUI builder to the Submit Button the callback function respondToSubmit + fileName, see picture above. Now the code runs to the function respondToSubmit() after pressing the submit button but in the line e.parameter.fileName; fileName is undefined. I assumed here also that the code somehow finds the fileName parameter from the FileUpload element so I wrote no code in doGet(). Any adwises?

Comment: ok. Have you defined doPost as doPost(e) rather than doPost(). Also, can you put in your most recent code here again

Comment: I added a new screenshot of GUI builder and the code of function doPost(e). The code never runs to function doPost(e) after selecting file with FileUpload button and pressing SubmitButton --> Error encountered: An unexpected error occured. I added the UI elements FileUpload and SubmitButton With GUI builder in FormPanels, defined as Name of FileUpload button FileUpload1, see screen shot, and wrote the function doPost(e), see RECENT CODE. I added nothing in function doGet().