# How to get the file name selected by FileUpload without submit button?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for how to get the file name by the ***FileUpload*** just by the file selected before a submit button pushed. But it seems not allowed.

I think the following code can probably hold up the ***FileUpload*** changed.

```
function doGet() 
{   
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();   

  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');

  var fileUploader = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile');  

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('fileChangeHandler');  
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  fileUploader.addChangeHandler(handler);

  panel.add(fileUploader);   

  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  form.add(panel);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;  
}
```

But I don't know how to grab the file name in ***fileChangeHandler()***. For example, the following is a failed code:

```
function fileChangeHandler(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();   

  Logger.log(e.parameter.thefile);

  return app;
}
```

Thanks very much for your comments ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload at google apps script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264423/file-upload-at-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a regular button for FileUpload, you must use a SubmitButton. See these two answers.

[GAS: GUI Builder, File Upload, Submit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420300/gas-gui-builder-file-upload-submit-button/12422223#12422223)

[File upload at google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264423/file-upload-at-google-apps-script)